# Leveraging IdentityServer4 in an existing eco system

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, windows-authentication, identityserver4

I'm currently on a project where there is an existing angular 1.3 app with a couple of API's. These are secured via Azure Active Directory.

The customer has asked for a new tool to be developed that uses these same api's but they want to get rid of the AAD because it's tokens are only valid for 1h and I've been told that refresh tokens and AAD are not working according to those that made the current setup.

I've been reading up a lot on IdentityServer4 and I was hoping to leverage the middleware in order to 
a) start using an STS
b) prepare for the future and make the STS a central part to the whole installation.

I've been hoping that I could use IdentityServer4 with a new to be developed Angular4 app with an Asp .NET Core 2.0 WebApi.

The question that I have is: can I do Active Directory based auth (the users are logging in through some citrix alike product) and thus are authenticated because of that. Yet somehow still calling the existing api's with some token that is valid in their context.

And can I use IdentityServer4 to pull this off? Is it a good idea? I'm open for suggestions

## Edit

After careful delibiration with the client we've agreed to remove AAD and the token security that currently is in place.
The reasoning:

1. All installations are done in a DMZ
2. It's not Azure
3. The customer isn't willing to change that
4. This way everything can be secured using Windows Authentication
5. Time constraints
6. IS is on the planning for when (5) loosens up
7. A lot of new tech is going to go in the new client which enforces (5)

Comment: Seems to me like you've got a (rather intricate and possibly big) architecture question here, not sure if SO can help. I suggest talking more to the customer, and having architecture sessions with peers to figure this one out.

Comment: What are the token lifetime requirements for your application use case? You can read about the token lifetimes offered by AAD [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes). Also, this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp) may be useful reference for your existing project.

Comment: Short answer: yes. You can use Windows authentication in IS, but issue tokens for APIs based on that. https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/windows.html